# Elasticsearch Timezone?

Tags: elasticsearch, timezone

In my mapping I defined

```
"Time": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
```

When I used the following query

```
"range": {
                "Time": {
                  "gt": "now-1h"
                }
              }
```

Rather than showing the documents for last hour it is showing the documents for the past 3-4 hours.

My documents has a Time field like this `"Time": "2017-02-10T10:07:04.4367673+00:00"`

I think it is in UTC format.
Thanks..

Comment: 1. What is the date/time of the machine where elasticsearch is installed? 2. what is your elasticsearch version?

Comment: Date/time of machine is 2/21/2017 & 6.47 PM , ES 2.4.1

Comment: I think you might have a timezone issue. Both should be in the same timezone

Comment: How can i change them to same timezone?

Comment: For your version (2.4.x), check this here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/mapping-date-format.html

Comment: @JonyD - No, no no....  The time zone of the server should always be treated as irrelevant.  Don't change the server's time zone to hack around a coding problem.  Fix the coding problem.

Comment: @C.Yaswanth - Do you get the correct results if you use the `basic_date_time` built-in format, or if you use a custom format `yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSSSSSZ`?  Also, you showed an example of 10:00 AM UTC in the above.  What time was it in UTC when you ran the query?  Are you comparing UTC to UTC?  Or are you writing local time values with a zero offset by mistake?  (BTW, petpeeve, but "UTC" is a system of timekeeping, or a reference time.  Not a "format".)

Comment: @Matt Johnson yes, that is why I posted the link for the ES mapping format so the OP can change the format

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found any solution?